# How to create a FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want to create a FlatList, Grid List or a View off numColum={3} for my

```
{folderToDisplay.map((item) => {
        return <Text key={item.id}>{item.value}</Text>;
      })}
```

right now my text is a list row. How to make it a colum off 3?

Comment: Since you can apparently not use grid, You can use flex box  instead https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wv0kjsirso
Also you can use React-native ```FlatList``` component too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FlatList numColumns doesn't appear to be working correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43507978/flatlist-numcolumns-doesnt-appear-to-be-working-correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FlatList with `numColumns` props.

```
<FlatList
    data={folderToDisplay}
    renderItem={({ item }) => <Text key={item.id}>{item.value}</Text>}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    numColumns={3}
  />
```

https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist

Comment: Thank you so much for your help mate

Answer (score 0):

**numColumns**

Multiple columns can only be rendered with **horizontal={false}**.

> **FlatList in React-Native**

```js
<FlatList
    contentContainerStyle={{margin:4}}
    horizontal={false}
    numColumns={4}
    data={this.state.categoryDataSource}
    renderItem={(item) =>
        return <Text key={item.id}>{item.value}</Text>;
        }
    keyExtractor={category => category.id}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, mate.